# How to disable/remove the quick create in the Lightning Experience's Lookup Field?

Tags: lightning-experience, lookup-field, quick-create

Follow the article...

URL: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000325372&type=1&mode=1

The "Show Quick Create" has been deselected.

[image]

However, the "+ New ..." still displays in the lookup fields in the Lightning Experience.

[image]

Does anyone have the same issue as this? And, how to disable/remove the quick create in the Lightning Experience's Lookup Field?

Answer (score 1):

Help article [Hide the 'Quick Create' section from overview pages](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000325372&type=1&mode=1)
 says:

> **This is only available in Classic**.  Reference this Idea on the [IdeaExchange](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A0000003RJGQA2).

This is not possible in lightning at the moment, only thing can be done is to upvote the idea [Ability to disable new record creation from Lightning Look up](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A0000003RJGQA2) and hope salesforce will add this feature.